# List of Lists in C++

Tags: c++, list

so Ive recently begun to learn c++, and I wanted to make a c++ version of a sudoku solver I had made using Python.

The board it uses is actually a list of lists, so in python it would look like:

```
board = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
[0, 5, 6, 7, 1]
]
```

How can I replicate this in c++?

Comment: A vector of vectors would probably work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you use `vector`s

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> board{
    std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4,5},
    std::vector<int>{6,7,8,9,0},
    std::vector<int>{0,5,6,7,1}};
```

Comment: don't forget to `#include <vector>`